# I want to walk,run,and jump by Gear vr

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I tried to do a unity project,i want to move(walk,run,jump)by Gear vr,how can i do?I know try Acceleration sensor and Gyro sensor,but i don't know how to use smart phone to do it.
Sorry ! i come fron asian ,my english not good. haha!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html
and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vkRtsaP3co (Video about installing software -> complete app)
These should get you started.

Comment: I mean,if i walk and object movement in Gear vr